# Match at least one character and one number, regardless of order, with no suffix?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a RegEx that fulfills this statement:

> **There is at least one character and one digit, regardless of order, and there is no suffix (i.e. domain name) at the end.**

So I have this test list:

```
ra182
jas182
ra1z4
```

And I have this RegEx:

```
[a-z]+[0-9]+$
```

It's matching the first two fully, but it's only matching the `z4` in the last one. Though it makes sense to me why it's only matching that piece of the last entry, I need a little help getting this the rest of the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the first two conditions with lookaheads:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])/i
```

... and if the third one is just about the absence of `.`, it's simple to check too:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[^.]+$/i
```

But I'd probably prefer to use three separate tests instead: with first check for symbols (are you sure it's enough to check just for a range - [a-z] - and not for a Unicode `Letter` property?), the second for digits, and the final one for this pesky dot, like this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(string, "[a-zA-Z]") 
    && Regex.IsMatch(string, "[0-9]")
    && ! Regex.IsMatch(string, @"\.") ) 
{ 
    // string IS valid, proceed
}
```

The regex in the question will try to match one or more symbols, followed by one or more digits; it obviously will fail for the strings like `9a`.

Comment: the first one would probably benefit from a `^` as well, and I think all the `.*` in the lookaheads are unnecessary.

Comment: Would using the first one, with the `$` (which is the end of a string right?) work to ensure they couldn't append any suffix?

Comment: @BigM that wouldn't match anything anymore, because then the lookahead would start at the end of the string, where they can't match any more

Comment: @m.buettner Indeed, it doesn't make any sense to check for the following `.*`. Fixed. )

Comment: @m.buettner the first `.*` is required. Otherwise the lookaheads will prevent any match, since the lookaheads need to occur immediately after the current "position", and a character cannot be both number and letter at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*\.).*");
```

or

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[.]).*");
```

or

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[^.]*$");
```

or

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^.]*\d[^.]*$");
```

---

```
if (match.Success) ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to match alphanumeric strings that have at least one letter and one number? Try something like this:

```
\w*[a-z]\w*[0-9]\w*
```

This will make sure you have at least one letter and one number, with the number after the letter. If you want to take into account numbers before letters, just use the corresponding expressiong (numbers before letters) and `|` the two.